# Left invertible non-square matrices and their sub-matrices over a commutative ring

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $$ A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 \\
1 & 4 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

The matrix $A$ has [rank](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Emurray/amwiki/index.php/FAQ:_What_does_it_mean_for_a_non-square_matrix_to_be_full_rank%3F) two (=number of independent columns), so it is full, [hence](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Eshinms/SP14-54/left-right-invertible-matrices.pdf#:%7E:text=Let%20A%20be%20an%20m%20n%20matrix.%20We,A%20is%20both%20left%20invertible%20and%20right%20invertible.) has a left inverse which is
$$ A_L=
\begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & 1 & 0\\ 
2 & -1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
(It is easy to check that $A_LA=I_{2 \times 2}$).

$A$ has three invertible square sub-matrices:
$ A_{1,2}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
$
$ A_{1,3}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 4 
\end{pmatrix} 
$
$ A_{2,3}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1 \\
1 & 4 
\end{pmatrix} 
$.
Each of the three sub-matrices is invertible, but generally it may happen that there are non-invertible sub-matrices, as the following example shows:
Let $$ B=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
$ B_{1,2}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
$
$ B_{1,3}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
$
$ B_{2,3}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} 
$.
Here $B_{1,3}$ is not invertible.

> **Claim 1:** Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix over $k$, $m > n$.
> Assume that $A$ is left invertible (hence all $m$ columns of $A$ are $k$-linearly independent).
> Then there exists an $n \times n$ sub-matrix of $A$ which is invertible (equivalently, has an invertible determinant =  a nonzero determinant, since we work over a field $k$).

**Question 1:** Is Claim 1 true? It seems true and follows from the assumption that $A$ has rank $m$.

> **Claim 2:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix over $k$, $m > n$.
> Assume that $A$ is left invertible (hence all $m$ columns of $A$ are $R$-linearly independent, so they generate a free $R$-module of rank $m$).
> Then there exists an $n \times n$ sub-matrix of $A$ which is invertible (equivalently, has an invertible determinant =  the determinant is an invertible element of $R$, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221681/invertible-matrices-over-a-commutative-ring-and-their-determinants)).

**Question 2:** Is Claim 2 true? It seems true if Claim 1 is true or am I missing something?
Maybe the result of left invertibility is not equivalent to having full column rank $m$? (I think this result stull holds. see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536019/properties-of-matrices-over-integral-domains)).

Thank you very much! I apologize if my question is trivial.

**Edit:** Maybe all we can say is that there is square $n \times n$ sub-matrix $S$ of $A$ with non-zero determinant $d_S \in R$, but this does not imply that $S$ itself is an invertible matrix, since $d_s$ may not be invertible in $R$.
The following is not a counterexample: $A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
t \\ 
t
\end{pmatrix} 
$.
$A$ has rank one, $S=
\begin{pmatrix} 
t
\end{pmatrix}
$ is not invertible, but $A$ itselt is *not* left invertible!

Comment: The size of the largest non-singular matrix is known as the determinantal rank of the matrix. It is known, in the field case, that it is [the same as the row/column rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826961/equivalence-of-determinantal-definition-or-rank-and-rowrank-definition-of-rank). I don't know about commutative rings though.

Comment: @user376343. thank you! I have changed the $1$ in the second row to $-1$.

Comment: @TheoBendit, thank you very much! You can write your comment as a partial answer. I think/hope that the same result holds over commutative rings, but I have not carefully checked all the details yet.

Comment: @TheoBendit, maybe there would be a problem if we work over a commutative ring which is not a field...Instead of nonzero minors we should consider invertible minors. I will try to find a counterexample over $R=\mathbb{C}[t]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over a commutative ring it is better to relate determinants to values taken in the image of your matrix [Cramer's Rule] and the minors do relate to surjectivity in the following way:

Since $A^T$ has a right inverse it is surjective and **the proper claim is** its $n\times n$ minors generate the unit ideal.  [In a PID like $\mathbb Z$ you can also talk about a gcd of $1$.] With $R$ denoting the commutative ring, define $B:=A^T$ and we know $I_n = BC$ for some $C\in R^{m\times n}$.

Proof:
$1 = \det\big(I_n\big) = \det\big(BC\big) = \sum_{S} \det\big(B_{[n],S}\big)\det\big(C_{S,[n]}\big) = \sum_{S} \det\big(B_{[n],S}\big)\cdot \alpha_k$
by Cauchy-Binet [a polynomial identity that holds over $\mathbb C$ so it holds over every commutative ring.  Ref e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula for notation clarifications though the OP has flipped the roles of $m$ and $n$.]  You can of course transpose this at the end to talk about minors of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a counterexample to Claim 2:
$M=
\begin{pmatrix} 
t+1 \\ 
t
\end{pmatrix} 
$.
$M$ is left invertible:
$M_L=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} 
$.
Each of the two sub-matrices is not invertible:
$M_{1,1}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
t+1
\end{pmatrix} 
$, $M_{2,1}=
\begin{pmatrix} 
t
\end{pmatrix} 
$.